# How to expose a regular file folder (and its files) in VS 2008 Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How to expose a regular file folder (and its files) in VS 2008 Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the ShowAllFiles button at the top of Solution Explorer should do it.

Comment: It shows foloders insider project folder, but I want to show a folder that is outside of any of the project folders, is there a way of doing that?

Comment: No, you can't show a folder outside of the project. Why do you want to do that in VS? You could just look at it using Windows Explorer.

Comment: It's a folder containing scripts that will be shared among projects.
But I want to see the scripts in VS because I want to use VS integrated version control over the scripts, which WExplorer cannot provide.Thanks.